# How to setup multi-module maven project with proper release and version structure

Tags: maven-2, maven-release-plugin, multi-module

I could not find the best practice for my  multi-module maven project,in terms of versioning, release and osgi bundles,

First of all Versioning and relase. my project has 5-6 sub modules with 200+ jar so wanted to use aggregation,

Case 1: Not to specify project versions and use parent version

- in this case if i use maven release
  plugin both tagging and pom.next is
  ok  for development (ok means jar3
  will always use latest version of
  jar1 which is same with itself)but
  what if i need to make patch relase
  only for jar1 ? how can i manage to
  make relase  (it says Can't release
  project due to non released
  dependencies parent:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT)
  and if i manage to release jar1
  0.0.1.1 ,how to say jar3 to use patched version of jar1?

  Parent Proejct (0.0.1-Snapshot)
    Module1 
      Jar1
      Jar2
    Module2
      Jar3
        (dependencies)[Jar1(project.version),Jar2(project.version)]
      Jar4
        (dependencies)[Jar1(project.version),Jar3(project.version)]

Case 2: Maybe it is good idea to specify jar versions in property file of parent pom

- in this case when use release plugin
  unfortunetly when i check pom.next i
  see that both jar version and
  dependency versions are reverted to
  hardcoded instead of property
  (jar1.version) so that for next
  release i will not be able to use
  properties , and second problem is
  even i manage to solve 1st problem
  maven release plugin does not change
  properties so next release  will use
  unmodified versions from properties

  Parent Proejct 
    Properties
      jar1.version
      jar2.version
      jar3.version
      jar4.version
    Module1 
      Jar1(jar1.version)
      Jar2(jar2.version)
    Module2(0.0.1-Snapshot)
      Jar3(jar3.version)
        (dependencies)[Jar1,Jar2]
      Jar4(0.0.1-Snapshot)
        (dependencies)[Jar1,Jar3]

I am kind of confused, didnt thought that relase and patch procedure would be that difficult, what is the best way to manage this kind of requirements with maven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i managed to  support release(version) management for my multi-module project with //dependencyManagement\

My parent pom

```
    <project>
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.seyn</groupId>
 <artifactId>hophop</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>pom</packaging>
 <name>hophop</name>

 <scm>
  <connection></connection>
  <developerConnection></developerConnection>
  <url></url>
 </scm>

 <properties>
  <hophop1.version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</hophop1.version>
  <hophop2.version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</hophop2.version>
 </properties>

 <modules>
  <module>../hophop1</module>
  <module>../hophop2</module>
 </modules>

 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>

 <dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>com.seyn</groupId>
    <artifactId>hophop1</artifactId>
    <version>${hophop1.version}</version>
   </dependency>
  </dependencies>
 </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

and my module 1 pom :

```
 <project>
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <parent>
  <artifactId>hophop</artifactId>
  <groupId>com.seyn</groupId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <relativePath>..\hophop</relativePath>
 </parent>
 <groupId>com.seyn</groupId>
 <artifactId>hophop1</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

 <scm>
  <connection>seyn</connection>
  <developerConnection>seyn</developerConnection>
  <url>seyn</url>
 </scm>

</project>
```

and my module 2 pom that depends module 1:

```
    <project>
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <parent>
  <artifactId>hophop</artifactId>
  <groupId>com.seyn</groupId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <relativePath>..\hophop</relativePath>
 </parent>
 <groupId>com.seyn</groupId>
 <artifactId>hophop2</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <scm>
  <connection>seyn</connection>
  <developerConnection>seyn</developerConnection>
  <url>seyn</url>
 </scm>
 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.seyn</groupId>
   <artifactId>hophop1</artifactId>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: How is it not complaining about you not having a version for the dependency on com.seyn:hophop1?

Comment: @Peter: because of
"
 <dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>com.seyn</groupId>
    <artifactId>hophop1</artifactId>
    <version>${hophop1.version}</version>
   </dependency>
  </dependencies>
 </dependencyManagement>
"

Comment: How would release:prepare work with this? Surely it would see that there are still snapshot dependencies?